# quasi-ordinary singularities on a versal deformation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Let $V$ be a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose $O$ is a singular point of $V$. Are there conditions on $(V,O)$ such that a versal deformation $W$ of $(V,O)$ has only quasi-ordinary singularities.

In particular, if we assume $(V,O)$ is a plane curve singularity (or, more generally, a quasi-ordinary singularity), then is there some condition which will force a versal deformation $W$ of $V$ to have quasi-ordinary singularities?

Comment: Infinitesimal deformations of isolated plane curve singularities, or more generally of isolated local complete intersection singularities, are unobstructed.  Thus, every hull is formally smooth.